# Retrieve single Row from dataset with help of ado.net

Tags: ado.net

I Want To retrieve last to second and third row from dataset

```
var lastUploaded = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("video_id")).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following Ans Gives Second Row:

```
ds.Tables["title"].Rows[ds.tables["title"].rRows.count-2][" Column name here"].ToString();
```

Third Row:

```
ds.Tables["title"].Rows[ds.tables["title"].rRows.count-3][" Column name here"].ToString();
```

And so on...